# Service Worker not caching html file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, offline-caching, service-worker

This is my service worker:

```
'use strict';


const CACHE_VERSION = 1;
let CURRENT_CACHES = {
  offline: 'offline-v' + CACHE_VERSION
};
const OFFLINE_URL = 'offline.html';

function createCacheBustedRequest(url) {
  let request = new Request(url, {cache: 'reload'});

  if ('cache' in request) {
    return request;
  }

  let bustedUrl = new URL(url, self.location.href);
  bustedUrl.search += (bustedUrl.search ? '&' : '') + 'cachebust=' + Date.now();
  return new Request(bustedUrl);
}

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(

    fetch(createCacheBustedRequest(OFFLINE_URL)).then(function(response) {
      return caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.offline).then(function(cache) {
        return cache.put(OFFLINE_URL, response);
      });
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {

  let expectedCacheNames = Object.keys(CURRENT_CACHES).map(function(key) {
    return CURRENT_CACHES[key];
  });

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (expectedCacheNames.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {

            console.log('Deleting out of date cache:', cacheName);
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {

  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' ||
      (event.request.method === 'GET' &&
       event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
    console.log('Handling fetch event for', event.request.url);
    event.respondWith(
      fetch(createCacheBustedRequest(event.request.url)).catch(error => {

        console.log('Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.', error);
        return caches.match(OFFLINE_URL);
      })
    );
  }


});
```

It's the standard offline cache service worker:
     https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/

I get no error in console.

On Android Chrome, adding the page to home page works fine (I've a manifest that defines the icon and URL). However, when I turn off my connectivity on the phone, I get an error message:

```
 Not Found
 The requested URL/offline.html was not found on this server.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does the `offline.html` file exist?

Comment: Of course. The file exists and opens fine. But it's not being cached.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in the way I configured my domains - I have mapped my / domain to my /www domain. I changed the const OFFLINE_URL = 'offline.html'; to const OFFLINE_URL = 'https://example.com/offline.html'; and it worked. Using an absolute URL works all the time.

Comment: So it actually didn't exist at the address that you were requesting :D